# How can I create a heat map based on data from Google Analytics?

Tags: geolocation, google-analytics, heatmap

How would one go about creating a heat map (say, of the US) based on location data from Google Analytics?  I'd like to somehow create such a map with the visitor data from several websites that use Google Analytics.  I'm not really looking for a step-by-step tutorial, just some suggestions on how to start.  Assume little to no programming experience, but a willingness to learn and hack together stuff to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Why recreate the wheel?

Simply go to the site, then click `Map Overlay` and you should be able to click on a country and see a heatmap - You can copy and paste that. For example

[image]

If you need to actually generate your own from a whole set of data, I am not aware of any good tools to let you do it.

Comment: That would work great, except that I need to combine data from multiple websites.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Charts API for interactive charts includes a mapping function.  It may do what you're looking for.

http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/